# converting a dictionary into 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a dictionary

```
clues={#:A,+:B,6:C}
```

into

```
clues1=[#,+,6]
clues2=[A,B,C]
```

when I use clues.values it doesn't let me iterate through it and any other method I have used has given an error message

Comment: what do you mean `it doesn't let me iterate through it`? What error message? Please be specific!

Comment: @njzk2 Perhaps he missed out the brackets, looking at the question (maybe?).

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to set `keys` to `clues1` and `values` to `clues2`?

```
clues1 = list(clues.keys())
clues2 = list(clues.values())
```

Comment: You do not need to put them into `list` ... `keys()` and `values()` do return lists already.

Comment: Otherwise, you can also assign both in a single statement, like: `clues1, clues2 = clues.keys(), clues.values()`

Comment: It doesn't. they can be `<class 'dict_keys'>` and `<class 'dict_values'>` respectively. checked on `2.7.5` and `3.3.2`

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to be true in Python 3.4, but I can still see the results I am proposing in Python 2.7.6 ... Ah well, since the question is for Python 3, I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the lists to be in alphabetical order, but still have the indicies match, you can do:

```
clues={'#':'A','+':'B','6':'C'}

cluesKeys = list(clues.iterkeys())
cluesValues = list(clues.itervalues())
```

Comment: @mskimm Actually it doesnt. I just ran it with Python 2.7.6, plus even if it did, the OP has `python-3.x` as a tag so it wouldn't matter either way.

Comment: @mskimm https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iterkeys

Comment: Oops sorry. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly want an iteration over the "clues" dictionary:

```
clues={'#':'A','+':'B','6':'C'}
clues1=list()
clues2=list()

for keys, values in clues.items():
    clues1.append(keys)
    clues2.append(values)

print clues1
print clues2

['#', '+', '6']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```